# What is the correct syntax for setting a custom boolean property in angular2

Tags: dart, angular

I would like to set a boolean property on an angular2 component.

Given the following (that is incorrect) ...

### .dart

```
@Component
....
@Input()
bool hasColour = false;
```

### .html

```
...
<span [class.blue-colour] = 'hasColour'></span>
...

<colour-component hasColour></colour-component>
```

... how can I fix the above to be able to use hasColour to bind a class?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind to the hasColour input property:

```
<colour-component [hasColour]="true"></colour-component>
```

Comment: I thought the presence of the property was enough to say it is true, like the required property. Why don't I have to put [required] = 'true', but just required?

Comment: When you bind to an Input property, you need to use the proper binding convention ([property]="value"). If you are specifying an attribute directive (like required), then the binding convention is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The solution does work too!